# How to get a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, var

From a page containing (or referring to) my JavaScript I do an AJAX XHR request to an external Web site.

The external Web site return on our GET request a JavaScript file like this:

```
var __xxx = {
    // ....
};
```

How do I get the value of the variable `__xxx` in my JavaScript?

Currently, the only way I invented is to remove `var __xxx` using a regular expression and parse the remaining using a JSON parser. Is there a better way?

The external Web site may be considered as trusted if necessary, but I would prefer not to trust the data from it (using some safe parser like JSON).

Comment: You could create a `<script>` tag on you page and insert the JS code into it

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I need to retrieve this value not once on page loading, but (probably several times) on keyboard events. Should I remove a `<script>` and re-create it for every event?

Comment: not much you can do if that is the format could eval it or new Function, but than that is security risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new function utilizing strings and the `Function` constructor. Add 'return _xxx;' and assign the result to a new variable that is accessible in your current script.

```
var returned_data = new Function(data + " return _xxx;")()
```

This is **preferable** to `eval` because the execution of the function will not allow access to local variables outside of the function scope.

Comment: And this will execute any other random code so it is not really the best solution.

Comment: @epascarello as opposed to what? This is a bit of a ridiculous scenario. It's never going to be good when you're working with external scripts that you can't touch and aren't sure you trust. In that vein this is probably the safest way, though obviously It's still not advisable.

Comment: Like the OP said.... strip off the leading variable declaration and run it through the JSON.parse which is more secure.

Comment: @epascarello That requires, still, that you know explicitly what's in the returned script or it won't run, and if that's the case, then this solution is just as pragmatic.

Comment: But if someone slips in window.open(), alert, window.location.href, etc into the code, it will not run it if you match the pattern.... If you trust it, sure go ahead, but if there is any way the data could change on you, is it worth the risk?

Comment: @epascarello probably not? That's up to OP. I'd never play with scripts that I couldn't say with certainty were safe, but this is more of a how than a why - and it is certainly safer than eval.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best options are to either do what you are currently doing (parse the string Javascript and `JSON.parse` it) or to use the `eval` method on the incoming Javascript string.

I would personally recommend parsing the string, but it depends on the Javascript you're returning from this endpoint. Eval would almost certainly work in either case, but can be dangerous